# Is there a better way to set the Gate without defining in each method?

Tags: laravel, acl

I'm using the permission role package by `Spatie`.
There's two ways that I know to prevent the user to access the controller methods.

**1. __construct**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('permission:show products');
    $this->middleware('permission:create products', ['only' => ['create','store']]);
    $this->middleware('permission:edit products', ['only' => ['edit','update']]);
    $this->middleware('permission:destroy products', ['only' => ['destroy']]);
}
```

**2. Each method**

```
 public function edit()
    {
        //
        if (Gate::denies('edit products')) {
            //get out
        }
        //do something
    }

    public function show()
    {
        //
        if (Gate::denies('show products')) {
            //get out
        }
        //do something
    }
```

Is there a better way to do it without defining on each method?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [Middleware Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#middleware-groups). This makes it possible to group a collection of routes and apply middlewares to all routes in that group.